# Speedtest: Why are some devices limiting despite there should be almost no difference?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

I have different devices testing the internet speed. The first number is the download speed in Mbps and the second number is the upload speed in Mbps (see this [video](https://youtu.be/gnJEwdVtbcU) comparing Alpha, iPhone and Windows machine 1):

- [Samsung Galaxy Alpha SM-G850F with Android 4.4.4 (802.11ac/802.11n)](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_alpha-6573.php): 90 / 10
- [iPhone 4S with iOS 8.3 (802.11n)](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_4s-4212.php): 35 / 30
- Windows machine 1 with Win 7 (100 MBit LAN): 90 / 30
- Windows machine 2 with Win 7 (100 MBit LAN): 90 / 10
- Windows machine 3 with Win XP (100 MBit LAN): 90 / 20

I know that there are differences at which time you test and also which connection you have. Therefore the speeds shown above are the values you get most of the time and they are repeatable.

The mobile devices are in the same room as the WLAN access point and there are no obstacles. The position of the devices is nearly the same (side by side). It can be observed that the Android device is limiting the upload speed to 10 MBit, whereas the iPhone is nearly hitting the internet connection speed limit (100 / 30). So the iPhone is not limiting on the upload speed, but on the download speed. It should be able to get the same download speed than on the Android device. Is this manufacturer specific? Before I never noticed it because I never that such sort of internet speed ...

On the PC side the behavior seems to be the same. One PC (Windows machine 1) has always better speeds. I have to mention that this device has nearly a direct connection to the router. Windows machine 2 has a longer cable line. Windows machine 3 has the longest cable line.

Imho the upload speed should reach the download speed. What does that mean? In my case I have an upload speed limit of 30 Mbit, but I'm only reaching 10 MBit on some devices. Why is this? I'm able to get the speed provided by my ISP, but it seems that the devices are limiting. E.g. on Windows machine 2 I'm able to get 90 MBit download speed. That means the wires are cabaple of 90 MBit, but not on the upload side. So a one-sided device limitation? It doesn't matter which speed test site I use.

Why is there a device limitation on speed?

Comment: What router is in use? Are you disconnecting all but one device while testing?

Comment: Router is Huawei B593s and the WLAN access point is Netgear Nighthawk X4 Smart WiFi Router (R7500) - AC2350. After searching for days I found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the used WLAN access point (Netgear Nighthawk X4 Smart WiFi Router (R7500)) was the cause. Firmware is V1.0.0.94. I replaced it with the D-Link DIR-100 and now I got full speed on all devices. The access point was not only used for WiFi but for all connections in house to the router (Huawei B593s). Now I use it also as access point, but the whole traffic isn't going over it anymore.

Strangely, one device is now getting full upload speed on the R7500. Perhaps routing everything over it was too much? But that wouldn't explain why some devices worked, and others not.